# How do I connect a function from another directory to Go/Echo?

Tags: go, echo

Created a project with structure:

```
lolo
--views
----count_private.go
--go.mod
--go.sum
--logs.log
--main.go
```

Code in `main.go`

```
package main

import(
"lolo/views"

"github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
e := echo.New()

e.GET("/f_count_private", views.F_count_private)

e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

Code in `count_private.go`

```
package views

import(
"net/http"

"github.com/labstack/echo"
)

func F_count_private(c echo.Context) error {
return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
}
```

When running the code via the `$ go run main.go` command, an error is thrown:

```
# lolo/views
views\count_private.go:9:6: F_count_private redeclared in this block
        views\cat.go:7:6: other declaration of F_count_private
```

Can you please tell me how to get around the error and make it so that I can use the `f_count_private(...)` function from another file in `main()`?

Comment: change function name F_count_private to `FCountPrivate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `views` package you import the `"github.com/labstack/echo/v4"` package.

In `main` you use `e.GET` from `github.com/labstack/echo/v4`, and in the `views` package you import `"github.com/labstack/echo"`

These are different packages for go, so the `echo.Context` type in the `FCountPrivate` definition is different from the `Context` type used in the `HandlerFunc` type from the `github.com/labstack/echo/v4` package.

Response @user:371023